# How to connect Google cloud SQL with PyMySQL?

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect GCP SQL database with PyMySQL using SSL. I'm using the following code so far.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=db_connection_name, user=db_user, password=db_password,
                           port=3306,
                           ssl={'ssl':{'ca':server-ca.pem,
                                       'key':client-key.pem,
                                       'cert':client-cert.pem}}
```

I'm getting the following error for this.

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

How do I solve the error?

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings on GCP and your device, opened ports and allowed IP´s?

Comment: Can you detail the pattern/format of data that you provide? Especially bd_connection_name? Does your database have a public IP? or only a private one?